# How to solve this npm error, I got while performing npm install? I can't find any solution to these errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, truffle

`npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path D:\greenchain\node_modules\sha3

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1

npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.18.2 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.5 found at "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

---

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

---

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Devyush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:113:11)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\Users\Devyush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:69:17)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir (C:\Users\Devyush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:26)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Users\Devyush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621

npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Devyush\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\greenchain\node_modules\sha3

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.2

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1

npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok`

I ran the command `npm install -g truffle && npm install`. And the truffle installation was smooth but halfway in npm install, I got these errors.